# Problem About Charity Fee

Tags: fees, bsc

I’ve successfully deployed this contract to BSC-Testnet and I’ve arranged the PancakeSwap testnet router. As you see in line 780, It’s my friend’s testnet wallet address but when I bought my token on PancakeSwap (test), the fee of charity which is 3% didn’t go to his address. (Also when I bought 1 token, it gives me 0.93) How can I fix this issue? Thank you so much!

https://www.paste.tc/basliksiz-578

Comment: Do you have the failed transaction hash?

Comment: Thank you so much! My friend told me that I need to change “_isExcludedFromFee[owner()] = true” to false. Have a nice day Ismael!